# Radius of convergence of $\sum z^{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the radius of convergence of the series  $\sum z^{n^2}$ . All I know is $\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ .
My intuitions says that it's ROC should be 1, as it can be seen as the sub series of $\sum z^{n}$ . But how can I prove it.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You have edited the question but not added anything.  The fact that it is a subseries of $\sum z^n$ is not important.  My original answer suggested the comparison test, which applies term by term.  Do you see how that applies here?

Comment: Ya it can be seen , as for |z|<1 we have  z^(n^2) < z^n and hence it's convergence follows.

Comment: Yes, that is the point I was making.  And if $|z| \gt 1...$

Comment: Certainly if |z|>1,we have z ^(n^2) >z^n  which diverges as  z^n diverges .

Comment: That makes the outline of the proof.  If you run into troubles, that would make a new question.

Comment: Is it enough to get an Upvote. @Ross Millikan  please give me one I want to ask more questions.

Comment: I don't know why you would be prohibited from asking questions as you have positive reputation and haven't asked any lately.  I am not one of the downvotes, but this question is just a homework problem with no effort shown.  The fact that you edited it without adding useful information could earn some more.

Comment: @RossMilkikan I don't know either , I have been blocked by the site to ask anymore questions .  I thought that getting Upvotes could help in this case , If you could help in removing those downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  compare with $\sum z^n$.

Comment: Now I am getting it , the only difference between these two series is their rate of convergence  one convergence with faster rate while the other with slower is it so??

Comment: It is true that the radius of convergence is $1$, but you need to prove it.  To prove it converges for $|z| \lt 1$ you can use the comparison test with the series I gave.  You need another tool for non-convergence for $|z| \gt 1$